# Delay in Unix chain of pipes

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I am trying to create a chain of pipes for 3 processes plus the current program such that:

1 - Exec P1 and send output of P1 to input of P2

3 - Send output of P2 to input of P3

4 - Display output of P3 in stdout

5 - Pass stdin of current/main/driver program to input of P3

I am using 2 pipes.  For task #5, the main program reads from stdin and writes to a pipe that P3 reads.

I have managed to get the processes communicating with each other.  However, what I noticed is there is a large delay between when P1 writes and when P2 detects this write on its STDIN, i.e. P1 may have written hundreds of times before P2 detects the write and misses many of the P1 writes at the beginning.  I have confirmed via print messages that P2 is in fact launched on time, however, it does not detect/read the input in time (it is a Python script looping: "for line in sys.stdin:" )

Here is my code:

```
int pipe1[2];
int pipe2[2];
if (pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0  )
{
    perror("Error: pipe");
}   


pid_t procIDC = fork();
if (procIDC == 0)
{       
    dup2(pipe2[0], 0);
    execv("procC", argv);           
}   
else
{       
    pid_t procIDB ;
    procIDB = fork();   

    if (procIDB == 0)
    {       
        dup2( pipe1[0], 0);  
        dup2( pipe2[1], 1);


        if (execl("/usr/bin/python", "/usr/bin/python", "./test.py", (char *)NULL) < 0)
        {
            perror("execl"); return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {           
        pid_t procIDA = fork(); 
        if (procIDA ==0)
        {       
            dup2( pipe1[1], 1);
            execv("proc1", argv);       
        }   
        else
        {                   
            dup2( pipe2[1], 1);

            //print any input so it sends to p3
            ssize_t read;   
            char *inputLine = NULL;
            size_t len = 0;        
            while ((read = getline(&inputLine, &len, stdin)) != -1) 
            {
                printf(inputLine);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was input buffering on STDIN in P2

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed is there is a large delay between when P1 writes and when P2 detects this write on its STDIN

Yes. Your question is presumably "why is there a delay"?

The answer: `stdio` (used by most programs) uses fully-buffered output *when* it detects that the output is going into a pipe.

To prevent that buffering, use `fflush` or `setvbuf`.

Some additional reading [here](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering).

> Actually, the fflush is obviously being done in the writing program

You didn't show us the writing program with `fflush` in it. If you had, we might be able to point out your mistake (`fflush` *will* help, if done correctly).

Anyway, one way to see what is happening is to run `strace -p <pid-of-writer>`, and observe that *immediately* after the writer actually executes the `write(2)` syscall, the reader gets its input. That would prove that it is in fact buffering in the writer that is causing the delay.

This:

> `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`

does not disable buffering. You really need to call `setvbuf` (or `fflush`).

Comment: I have actually tried this but it does not seem to help.
Also: I was thinking if after printf and flush I put a sleep in before subsequent prints, eventually this will be picked up by P2.  But instead, it looks like this only increased the amount of time between when P2 finally detect a read.  I don't understand!

Comment: @cppNoob You've only shown us the *reading* program. Adding `fflush` to *it* isn't going to make any difference: the delay is happening in the *writing* one. And *of course* putting a sleep into already slow program will only make it slower.

Comment: Actually, the fflush is obviously being done in the writing program and so is the sleep AFTER it writes

Comment: I would have thought that if in P1: printf then fflush(stdout) then some delay, eventually this will be read on P2.  But the delay makes it worse i.e. it seems like it is only read on P2 after certain amount of buffering as you said but I'm calling flush and also  setbuf(stdout, NULL);

Comment: I have tried setvbuf and also:
printf("hi\n");
fflush(stdout);